# Is it possible to store forms responses in a template document in a library using PowerAutomate?

Tags: power-automate, form, sharepoint-library, document-template, microsoft-forms

I know it's possible to save form answers in a list but it would be more practical for a team to have the answers directly filling out a template document in a library. I can't find information about it. Is it possible using PowerAutomate? Thank you!

Comment: This is what youre looking for, Reza Dorani will be your guide: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Webinars-and-Video-Gallery/How-to-save-Microsoft-Forms-Responses-amp-Attachments-to/td-p/1500350

Comment: Thanks. I watched the video already but it's for attachments. I would be interested to know if answers can be saved in a doc in a library.

Comment: Is this what youre trying to accomplish? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Populate-a-microsoft-word-template-based-on-Form-responses-and/td-p/861995